# Is it possible to render SVG elements directly in Svelte?

Tags: javascript, svg, svelte, rollup

I am trying to import and render SVG's in Svelte.

I am using [@rollup/plugin-url](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/url) to import the SVG code like so:

```
<script>
  import arrowCircle from "heroicons/dist/solid-sm/sm-arrow-circle-up.svg"
</script>

<main>
  <object title="Arrow Circle" type="image/svg+xml" data={arrowCircle}></object>
</main>
```

Now this works (in terms of the SVG content getting brought in) but it renders the following screen:

[image: Rendered SVG]

[image: Rendered SVG tag]

Ideally I would like to use the `<object />` element so I can apply classes to the SVG but given the error I thought I would have a go with the `<img />` tag to see if this would at least render the SVG, but instead got this:

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2020%2020%22%20fill%3D%22currentColor%22%3E%20%20%3Cpath%20fill-rule%3D%22evenodd%22%20d%3D%22M10%2018a8%208%200%20100-16%208%208%200%20000%2016zm3.707-8.707l-3-3a1%201%200%2000-1.414%200l-3%203a1%201%200%20001.414%201.414L9%209.414V13a1%201%200%20102%200V9.414l1.293%201.293a1%201%200%20001.414-1.414z%22%20clip-rule%3D%22evenodd%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E">
```

I also tried just `{arrowCircle}` but that rendered the above image `src` as plain text.

From what I can tell it is to do with the `data` prefix that is part of the raw import.

I am aware of the [codefeathers/rollup-plugin-svelte-svg](https://github.com/codefeathers/rollup-plugin-svelte-svg) plugin but would like to be able to do be able to do this without another plugin if possible, or at least understand what is going on.

For reference SVG are valid in both `<img />` tags as well as `<object />` as per this [article](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/).

Comment: Did you try adding the missing namespaces? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course

Comment: @RobertLongson do you mean to the SVG's themselves?

Comment: Yes, they are not valid SVG without namespces.

Comment: If an option you can rename your files to `.svelte` and use them as any other component, it will inline the SVG.

Comment: Hmmm I can see that they don't have the namespaces but I am also able to paste the raw SVG input in and they work...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks as though the SVG file isn't valid as a standalone image. Try this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ...>...</svg>
```

Comment: I've since realized the SVG's I want to load are intended for inline use only, which means I could use something like https://github.com/sionzeecz/rollup-plugin-inline-svg#readme or find another library, in terms of fixing the issue at hand your answer is correct.